# Forgot SQL Server Password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I installed SQL Server 2005 sometime ago and forgot the administrator password I set during setup. How can I connect to SQL server now?

**EDIT:** I think I only allowed Sql Server Authentication. Login with integrated security also does not work.

Comment: Just for clarification, this is **not** SQL Server 2005 Express you are referring to, correct?

Comment: I think this question belongs to ServerFault.com

Comment: [How to Reset SA Password in Sql Server](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-SA-Password-in-Sql-Server)

Answer (score 35):

Try running the following commands at the command prompt (assuming your Server name is **SQLEXPRESS**):

```
osql -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS
exec sp_password @new='changeme', @loginame='sa'
go
alter login sa enable
go
exit
```

Once you have completed these steps, try to login with username **sa** and password **changeme**.

Comment: I think this first command requires integrated account. Since when I try it, it says "Login failed for user 'mydomain\myuser'".

Comment: This answer assumes you already have access to your SQL server, otherwise you would get "Login failed" message, as expected.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to pay for any reset tools to do this.  Start the instance in single user mode and you can create a new login with sysadmin permissions/

See this [Pinal Dave link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/10/sql-server-start-sql-server-instance-in-single-user-mode/).

Comment: Yup, that's how I did it: http://serverfault.com/questions/120215/user-provisioning-tool-for-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot **cowgod**

It works Fine.
I have Logged in to SQL Server with windows authentication mode.
Then opened a new query window. There I typed these two commands by prssing F5.

First run
**exec sp_password @new='changeme', @loginame='sa'**

Then
**alter login sa enable**

Answer (score 3):

If there's no other user with sysadmin privileges but `sa`, SQL Server should be restarted with `-m` option for single-user mode. Then you can connect to this SQL Server instance and you're able to add other users with sysadmin role or to execute `exec sp_password`.

Pinal Dave explains here - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/10/sql-server-start-sql-server-instance-in-single-user-mode/ - how to add `-m` with **SQL Server Configuration Manager**: right-click server service, go to Advanced tab and add `-m;` (notice semicolon) in Startup Parameters.

Another way is to stop SQL Server instance in Services and to run it manually from the **command line** like this:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -m -sSQLEXPRESS

I had to do that for SQL Server 2008 as it didn't appear in SQL Server 2008 R2 Configuration Manager. Exect command line can be found with in service properties.

Comment: But How to add other users with sysadmin role?

Comment: Can't check it just now, but I remember that you simply start SQL Server Management Studio, connect to that instance, right-click the instance and choose "Add user..." Then in the dialog window there should be a checkbox for sysadmin privilege.

Comment: Thank you, I have just found it in details http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 1):

For these steps to work, you need to be an admin on box where SQL Server is installed.

- Stop SQL Server from configuration manager
- Start SQL Server in single user mode
- Add this `-mSQLCMD` command as one of the start up parameters, by right clicking the service and going into startup parameters section as shown in screenshot below and start SQL Server

  [image]
- Now connect to SQLSERVER from SQLCMD (open command prompt as admin) like below:

  ```
  sqlcmd -s servername\instancename
  ```

  And run below command:

  ```
  USE [master]
  GO
  CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
  GO
  EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\Administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
  GO
  ```

  Above command adds all local users as sysadmins. You may change this and add a user like or you can make another user sysadmin and remove `BUILTIN\Administrators`
- Once this is done, you need to now stop SQL Server and remove `-mSQLCMD` parameter and restart SQL Server

**References:**
[Help : I lost sa password and no one has System Administrator (SysAdmin) permission. What should I do?](https://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/)

Comment: THX a lot, you're a lifesaver. This helped be alot, because no one from our team was able to connect to the new SQL instance on EC2 and with this approach I was able to add myself as sys admin.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set it up to only accept SQL Server authentication, you can log on with integrated security using the administrator user of the domain and/or machine.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the local admin user or group wasn't added as an admin at install, this isn't an option.  Also, SQL Authentication by itself isn't an option.