# How can I reset username and password for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Shortly after I installed MS SQL Server 2008 on my machine, I forgot the password AND username that I chose.  How can I reset them?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237006/forgot-sql-server-password) seems promising, but it didn't work for me.

When I tried `exec sp_password @new='changeme', @loginame='sa'` as a query, I received:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: it sounds like you are able to run queries against the server. what is the login that you are using? What privileges do you have on that login?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try following the instructions from this blog post entitled [Disaster Recovery: What to do when the SA account password is lost in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx). It applies to SQL Server 2005, but should probably work with SQL Server 2008 as well.

You need to start SQL Server in single user mode using the `-m` command line switch. When SQL Server has started, a **Windows** administrator can connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication. You can then reset the password of the `sa` user. Make sure to restart SQL Server without the `-m` command line parameter afterwards.

Comment: Or edit the server's properties to include the `-m` switch, yes.

Comment: This works perfectly. I just reset the sa password on one of my development machines with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

Login as a Local or Domain Admins and just try to connect using "Windows Authentication".

Comment: Not for me though, so I guess we did not have the same problem.

Comment: On SQL Server 2008, local administrators do not have (by default) SQL Server administrator privileges.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have other SysAdmin privilege login - you have nothing but reinstall it.
Otherwise use it to change password.