# I forgot my sql server 2008 r2 username an password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed an instance of sql server on my machine a while back. 
I generally login via SSMS. I currently forgot the username and password for the instance.
Is there a way I can recover it.  I searched online including a pervious stack overflow post but didnt 
find it helpful. Is there anything I can do to recover my username and password ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reset username and password for SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087033/how-can-i-reset-username-and-password-for-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to [Troubleshooting: Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

> Start the instance of SQL Server in single-user mode by using either
>   the -m or -f options. Any member of the computer's local
>   Administrators group can then connect to the instance of SQL Server as
>   a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

And then try to do the following steps as explained by Remus Rusanu in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781365/how-to-change-sa-password-in-sql-server-2008-express/13333309#13333309).

> - shutdown MSSQL$EXPRESS service (or whatever the name of your SQL    Express service is)
> - start add the -m and -f startup parameters (or you can start    sqlservr.exe -c -sEXPRESS -m -f from console)
> - connect to DAC: sqlcmd -E -A -S .\EXPRESS or from SSMS use    admin:.\EXPRESS
> - run create login [machinename\username] from windows to create your    Windows login in SQL
> - run sp_addsrvrolemember 'machinename\username', 'sysadmin'; to make    urself sysadmin member
> - restart service w/o the -m -f