# sa user is locked out and login fails with Windows Authentication. Now what?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am logged in to a Windows 7 computer as an admin. I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 on the same machine. The SA account is locked out. When I try Windows Authentication, the login fails.

How do I log in now? Is there an external tool to unlock the SA user? I used an external tool to change the SA password. I don't want to reinstall the software.

Comment: Are you getting an error 18486??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forgot SQL Server Password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237006/forgot-sql-server-password); the single-user mode solution is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx) for SQL 2012

Comment: @Rahul Yes. I get error 18486.

Comment: Also see http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: @Pondlife. Your single-user solution worked. You can post the answer if you want the credit. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Thanks for the offer, but since this question is a duplicate, it should be closed rather than answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read and follow the steps described in [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx):

- start the server in administrative mode with `-m` or `-f`
- connect as a LUA elevated process (runas administrator)
- create a login for youserlf and add it to sysadmin group

Answer (score 1):

For unlocking sa, you just have to connect as a machine administrator to the server. The machine administrators are by default granted access to SQL Server. Once you connect as an administrator, you can run below query:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'new_password' UNLOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

When SQL Server SA account is locked out and fails to login with Windows Authentication mode, you can use the third party tool **Asunsoft SQL Password Geeker** to change/reset SA password.

Asunsoft SQL Password Geeker can instantly reset SA user and other users passwords on SQL Server 2012/2008/2005/20014.

**Important:** Before you open this tool, firstly stop SQL Server services. And when SA password is successfully reset, do not forget to close this tool and restart SQL Server services.

Now run this tool and do as below:

1. Click **Open File** button.
2. Browse for the master.mdf file and import it into this tool.
3. Select the **sa** user and click **Reset** button.
4. Type a new sa password and click **OK**.

If you need more details just refer to [**How to Use SQL Password Geeker**](http://www.asunsoft.com/guide/sql-password-geeker-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have no permissions to connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication or Windows Authentication is not available.

Besides login SQL Server 2008 Express with local admin account when Windows Authentication mode is available, there are still other ways that can effective reset SQL Server SA password, such as command and SQL password recovery tool.

To some extent, command would be more difficult to reset SA password than SQL password recovery tool. For example, SQL Password Genius has simplified steps to add master.mdf file, select SA account and set a new password for it. So several clicks has been OK to reset SA password with SQL password recovery tool. 
Details about how to reset SA password with command and tool are introduced here: http://www.isunshare.com/sql-password/four-effective-ways-to-change-sql-server-sa-password.html

Comment: While adding a link is beneficial, it is good to include the gist (of the content present at the URL) explicitly in your code. This is because links tend to change over time.