# Error connecting to SQL Server with Windows Authentication with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Tags: sql-server

I want to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication and create a SQL Server user.

The error I get while doing this is:

> Unable to connect: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
> Reason: The account is disabled.

I also get the following error when I try to connect with PsTools:

> Unable to connect: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
> Reason: The account is disabled.

What kind of process should I provide to activate the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user? Or how can I act?

Information: I didn't install SQL Server. Installed with the app I'm using but i have admin access

I can't create a user because I can't login with Windows Authentication

I can not access with SQL Server Management Studio

I logged in as administrator and wanted to reset passwords using SQL server management studio but unfortunately failed

Comment: Why are you trying to connect via `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` in the first place?

Comment: first you add a ouse to you windows/ Ad Domain and the add this user to the sql server user list.

Comment: you where able to login as administrator ? Then you should be able to reset passwords and enable accounts. What exact failed there ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forgot SQL Server Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237006/forgot-sql-server-password) . The same basic procedure applies if no suitable admin account was added during setup. (The system account is not a suitable admin account and should basically never be used, even if you could in theory add it as an admin.)

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15